# How can i add auto increment in vb.net with date, year and alphabets

Tags: .net, vb.net

codes are like this. But instead of getting new number im getting Feb-16-INV-00011 and Feb-16-INV-000111 and Feb-16-INV-0001111

```
Private Function newautonum()

    Dim NewValue As Integer
    'Dim result As String
    Dim resultN As String

    Dim ynow As String = DateTime.Today.ToString("yy")
    Dim Mnow As String = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMM")
    Dim Bilnow As String = Mnow & "-" & ynow & "-"

    Dim qry As String = "select MAX(ID) from tblTrns"

    ConObj = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
    ConObj.Open()

    CmdObj = New SqlCommand(qry, ConObj)
    resultN = CmdObj.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(resultN) Then
        resultN = Bilnow & "INV-000"
        ' resultN = result
    End If

    resultN = resultN.Substring(0)
    Int32.TryParse(resultN, NewValue)
    NewValue = NewValue + 1
    resultN = resultN + NewValue.ToString
    Return resultN

    ConObj.Close()
End Function
```

Now I Tried this but no luck.... Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid. Function of getnextvalue Error.

```
Private Function newautonum() As String

    Dim NewValue As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim qry As String = "Select MAX(ID) from tblTrns"

    ConObj = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
    ConObj.Open()

    CmdObj = New SqlCommand(qry, ConObj)
    result = CmdObj.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
        result = String.Format("{0}-INV-{1:000}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-yy"), NewValue)
    End If

    Int32.TryParse(result, NewValue)
    NewValue = GetNextValue()
    result = result & GetNextValue.ToString
    Return result

    ConObj.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: You should turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: tried this too. but the character $ is not valid?

Comment: use `resultN = retval = String.Format("{0}-INV-{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-yy"), newvalue.ToString("000"))` the answer posted is using a VS2015 feature

Comment: Im using VS2010. Will it work on 2010?

Comment: Dear Sir can u please complete my full answere

Answer (score 2):

You have everything you need there, it is just the formatting of the string that you don't have.

Assumuing that `NewValue` holds the next number you want to create the string for:

```
 Dim newValue = GetNextValue()
 resultN = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-yy")}-INV-{newValue:000}"
```

**Note** that if you are using Visual Studio 2013 or lower you will have to use String.Format instead of the $ shortcut:

```
resultN = String.Format("{0}-INV-{1:000}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-yy"), newValue)
```

I would suggest you have a separate function to return the next Value:

```
Private Function GetNextValue() As Integer
    Dim qry As String = "select MAX(ID) from tblTrns"

    ConObj = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
    ConObj.Open()

    CmdObj = New SqlCommand(qry, ConObj)
    Dim result = CmdObj.ExecuteScalar()

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return CInt(result) + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks sir. But i didnot understand this line. resultN = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-yy")}-INV-{newValue:000}"

Comment: I tried this too. but the character $ is not valid?